# Send put request with array of dictionaries with Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I am trying to send JSON put body request with the following. When I entered the JSON by hand as a string, it worked, but when I try to create it through code, it fails:

```
struct Item: Codable {
    let name: String
    let price: Float
}

struct User: Codable {
    let username: String
    let fullName: String
}

let item = Item(name: "pen", price: 0)
let itemData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(item)
let itemString = String(data: itemData, encoding: .utf8)!

let user = User(username: "Dave", fullName: "Dave Grohl")
let userData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(user)
let userString = String(data: userData, encoding: .utf8)!

let parametersJson: [String: Any] = [
    "item": itemString,
    "user": userString
]
```

The Alamofire request is as follows:

```
AF.request("http://127.0.0.1:8000/items/10",
       method: .put,
       parameters: parametersJson,
       encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
.response { (response) in
    debugPrint(response)
```

What I get as a response:

```
[Response Body]: 
{"detail":[{"loc":["body","item"],"msg":"value is not a valid dict","type":"type_error.dict"},{"loc":["body","user"],"msg":"value is not a valid dict","type":"type_error.dict"}]}
```

At the same time, when I use the following as parameters, it works fine:

```
let parameters: [String: [String:String]] = [
"item": [
    "name": "pen",
    "price": "0"
],
"user": [
    "username": "dave",
    "full_name": "Dave Grohl"
]
```

Any help is really appreciated.

#

As per Frankenstein comment, I have changed the User struct to correct for the mismatch between fullName and full_name, but still get the same error. When I debug print the request I get the following:

```
[Request Body]: 
{"user":"{\"username\":\"Dave\",\"full_name\":\"Dave Grohl\"}","item":"{\"name\":\"pen\",\"price\":0}"}
```

And this is what I get, when parameters (as defined above as a string) are used:

```
[Request Body]: 
{"item":{"name":"pen","price":"0"},"user":{"username":"dave","full_name":"Dave Grohl"}}
```

Comment: As per Frankenstein comment, I have changed the User struct to correct for the mismatch between fullName and full_name, but still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: The major issue here is that you're not formatting your `JSON` properly, Here is what you need to do:

```swift
struct Item: Codable {
    let name: String
    let price: Float
}
struct User: Codable {
    let username: String
    let fullName: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case username
        case fullName = "full_name"
    }
}
struct Parameter: Codable {
    let user: User
    let item: Item
}
let item = Item(name: "pen", price: 0)
let user = User(username: "Dave", fullName: "Dave Grohl")
let parameter = Parameter(user: user, item: item)

let data = try! JSONEncoder().encode(parameter)

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "PUT"
request.httpBody = data
AF.request(request).response { (response) in
    debugPrint(response)
    //...
}
```

Previous Answer: It's because your parameters have a mismatch in `User`. You can fix it by just modifying the `User` struct as follows:

```swift
struct User: Codable {
    let username: String
    let fullName: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case username
        case fullName = "full_name"
    }
}
```

An alternate approach is to use a custom `JSONDecoder` and set it's `keyEncodingStrategy` to `convertToSnakeCase`, like this:

```swift
let user = User(username: "Dave", fullName: "Dave Grohl")
let decoder = JSONEncoder()
decoder.keyEncodingStrategy = .convertToSnakeCase
let userData = try! decoder.encode(user)
let userString = String(data: userData, encoding: .utf8)!
```

Note: Usually the `JSON` format contains both snake-case and camel-case and hence using the first approach is the better choice in my opinion. But both would work.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I have updated the question above, but I still get the same error. It seems that json is not properly formatted for some reason

Comment: @IvanDolgushev I've added the entire code you need check out now.